# nameserver address not resolving, possible bind misconfiguration

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, centos5, nameserver

I have a CentOS based VPS, which I've started setting up to use it's own nameservers. The domain is registered elsewhere, and I've already registered the nameservers with my registrar.

On the server side, I've edited named.conf (I had a local view, so I created a public one: match-clients and match-destinations set to any) to include the new zone and created the zone file. After the setup I've tried digging the address of the nameservers, but I keep getting (normal dig, without @ returns info of the domain, without the IP of the ns):

```
dig: couldn't get address for 'ns1.example.com': not found
```

The domain in question is currently parked on another server, because I'm in the process of migrating the server.

Is the reason the dig command can't find the address connected with the fact that my domain is still parked elsewhere? Or have I misconfigured something?

Another possibility that springs into my mind. My named.conf has the statement option listen-on set to port 53 on 127.0.0.1. The allow-query was set to localhost, but I've already changed that to any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the ns1.example.com the nameserver for example.com? If so, have you setup GLUE records?

Comment: Yes, it's the same domain, and yes, I've setup the nameservers and the coresponding IPs at the registrar's end.

When I request the status of the nameserver from my registrar I receive confirmation that it's set to the correct IP, however it says it's not connected.

Comment: edit: I used http://www.webdnstools.com/dnstools/chk-domain to check my domain, and it says I have no GLUE records. Could this be due to my domain being pointed to another hosting provider at the moment, and listing them as the authoritative nameservers overwrites my own?

Comment: The GLUE records need to be setup with the registrar, and just determine where to resolve ns1.example.com (for example). If you don't have ns1.example.com as an authoritative nameserver, then the GLUE record is, by and large, pointless (in fact, if you had an A record of ns1 with them as well I'm not sure which would be read). What are the nameservers currently? If they are ns*.example.com, how are you pointing the domain at a different hosting provider?

Comment: I thought this might be the problem, thanks. I pointed the domain to it's own nameservers now, now I just need to wait for the changes to propagate through the net, to see if there's something else that might be misconfigured.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using custom name servers (ie: name servers set to ns1.YOURDOMAIN.com, etc...), you'll need to register the name servers with the registrar. It's a chicken or the egg problem with DNS. If you use ns1.YOURDOMAIN.com, when it comes time to resolve your records, public DNS servers need to know where to look for your records first.

Your registrar should give you the ability to register or map your name servers to IP addresses somewhere in their control panel. Once that's done, it should know where to look for your additional records.